# How to receive text from pdf in R properly?

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I want to make my own word embedding in R. I tried to open and receive text from pdf but it gives me this error: Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="goethe_faust.pdf": No file found

Weird is that this file exists and I can open it with any pdf reader. It's not password locked or something like that.
My code:

```
library(pdftools)
file_vector <- list.files(path = "pdf_collections")
pdf_text <- pdf_text(file_vector[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `list.files` just includes the file names. To open these files,  you will need to include your path (pdf_collections).  You can fix this by specifying that you want the full path to the files.

```
file_vector <- list.files(path = "pdf_collections", full.names=TRUE)
```